# EditText with attribute singline="true" doesn't moves up when keyboard appears

Tags: android

Reproduced on Nexus 7 android 4.3

Workflow:

1. Set focus to edit text first time - keyboard appears, EditText is
   visible;
   [image]
2. Hide Keyboard;
3. Set focdus to edit text second time - keyboard appears, EditText
   doesn't moving up.
   [image]

(EditText aligned on the bottom of the screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

I tried this: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or adjustPan|adjustResize , but now effect.

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

**Updates:**

**I figured out : the problem is in attribute  android:singline="true";** This attribute needed to show search button, and start search after it was cliked on keyboard - otherwise shown enter button after clicking wich we going to the next line.

**Q**: Does Your activity using FLAG_FULLSCREEN ?

**A**: Yes. But without this flag still reproduced.

Comment: Does Your activity using FLAG_FULLSCREEN ?

Comment: Does Your activity using FLAG_FULLSCREEN? : Yes

Comment: @Sinigami post your layout xml and activity code.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file under activity tag just add:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan"
```

will solve your problem!!

Answer (score 0):

you can't specify textfield with type actionSearch as a single line textfield.try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your manifest file, add to your activity

**

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

**